# QGIS: Raster to vector too large

Tags: raster, vector, vectorization, large-datasets

I am working with a DTM of 5x5m for a large area (already clipped it). I calculated the slopes and want to maintain only the slopes above 2 degrees. I already used the raster calculator to set all values above 2 to 1 and the rest to 0. However when I convert to a vector, I get a way too large vector file which results in only empty shapefiles once I try to do anything with it in the geoprocessing tools.

What I need is to be able to get an intersect (or clip) with another shapefile.

Is there a way to dissolve the different pixels with the same value before vectorizing the raster or some other way to be able to get an intersect between this way too large raster and my vector file?

Comment: How are you converting to vector because Polygonize should combine all contiguous cells of the same value into one polygon?

Comment: Hi MappaGnosis, I did use the Polygonize but the problem is that the resulting vector had a gigantic amount of attributes. This makes Qgis unable to do any actions on it. In the end I did the intersect in ArcGis. A pity Qgis seems unable to handle large vectors created by polygonising rasters.

Comment: Set the 0 to NA, then these parts will be ignored. This should at least speed up the process a bit.